# [Razorpay Subscription]: Can't use any other payment method in Razorpay Subscription then Cards, while in orders I can use multiple methods

Tags: razorpay

Besically I'm using Razorpay payment gateway, to make **Order** and **Subscription**
while making Order I can see a list of multiple payment methods but while making Subscription I am forced to pay through cards.
I want to recieve multiple payment methods while **Subscription Checkout**, just like I am getting in **Order Checkout**

I'm trying to make an Order payment in Razorpay via Checkout(**(new Razorpay()).open()**)

And I can see multiple payment methods as attached below.

#### Backend Code

```js
const instance = new Razorpay({
    key_id: process.env.KEY,
    key_secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
});

app.get("/createOrder", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        var options = {
            amount: 1000, // amount in the smallest currency unit
            currency: "INR",
        };
        const order = await instance.orders.create(options);
        if (!order) {
            throw new Error("The order not created");
        }
        res.status(200).json({
            status: true,
            msg: `Order Creation Success`,
            orderID: order.id,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error[createOrder]: ", error);
        res.status(500).json({
            status: false,
            error: error.message,
        });
    }
});
```

#### Frontend Code

```js
document.getElementById("order").addEventListener("click", async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(
                    "http://localhost:4000/createOrder"
                );
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error("Server error - 500");
                }
                const order = await response.json();
                console.log("Order status: ", order);
                if (!order.status && !order.orderID) {
                    return;
                }
                const options = {
                    key: "rzp_test_...", // Enter the Key ID generated from the Dashboard
                    amount: "1000", // Amount is in currency subunits. Default currency is INR. Hence, 50000 refers to 50000 paise
                    currency: "INR",
                    order_id: order.orderID, //This is a sample Order ID. Pass the `id` obtained in the response of Step 1
                    handler: function (response) {
                        console.log(
                            response.razorpay_payment_id,
                            response.razorpay_order_id,
                            response.razorpay_signature
                        );
                    },
                };
                const rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
                rzp1.open();
                rzp1.on("payment.failed", function (response) {
                    console.log("Payment Failed: ", response);
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Error: ", error.message);
            }
        });
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncmbh.png)

---

While I can't see any Payment Methods in options making a Subscriptions, I am forced to do a Card Payment

*I just want to allow other payment methods(mainly UPI) as well for subscriptions*

#### Backend Code

```js
const instance = new Razorpay({
    key_id: process.env.KEY,
    key_secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
});

app.get("/createSub", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const options = {
            plan_id: process.env.PLAN_ID,
            total_count: 4,
        };
        const sub = await instance.subscriptions.create(options);
        console.log(sub);
        res.status(200).json({
            status: true,
            msg: `Subscription Creation Success`,
            subID: sub.id,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error[createSub]: ", error);
        res.status(500).json({
            status: false,
            error: error.message,
        });
    }
});
```

#### Frontend Code

```js
document.getElementById("sub").addEventListener("click", async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/createSub");
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error("Server error - 500");
                }
                const sub = await response.json();
                console.log("Subscription status: ", sub);
                if (!sub.status && !sub.subID) {
                    return;
                }
                const options = {
                    key: "rzp_test_...",
                    subscription_id: sub.subID,
                    handler: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        fetch("http://localhost:4000/checkoutHandler", {
                            method: "POST",
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                data: [
                                    response.razorpay_payment_id,
                                    response.razorpay_order_id,
                                ],
                            }),
                            headers: {
                                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                                "x-razorpay-signature": `${response.razorpay_signature}`,
                            },
                        });
                    },
                    prefill: {
                        contact: "797...",
                    },
                };
                const rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
                rzp1.open();
                rzp1.on("payment.failed", function (response) {
                    console.log("Payment Failed: ", response);
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Error: ", error.message);
            }
        });
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRAgz.png)

Comment: Did you get a solution? Is there support from Razorpay?